# When can we exchange order of two limits?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

My questions are about a sequence or function with several variables.

- I vaguely remember some while ago one
  of my teachers said taking limits of
  a sequence or function with respect to
  different variables is not
  exchangeable everywhere, i.e.
  $$ \lim_n \lim_m a_{n,m} \neq \lim_m \lim_n a_{n,m}, \quad \lim_x \lim_y f(x,y) \neq \lim_y \lim_x f(x,y).$$
  So my
  question is what are the cases or
  examples when one can exchange the
  order of taking limits and when one
  cannot, to your knowledge? I would
  like to collect the cases together,
  and be aware of their difference and
  avoid making mistakes. If you could
  provide some general guidelines, that
  will be even nicer!
- To give you an example of what I am
  asking about, this is a question that
  confuses me: Assume $f: [0, \infty)
     \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ is a
  function, satisfying $$
     \int_0^{\infty} x f(x) \, dx < \infty.
     $$ Determine the convergence of this
  series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
     \int_n^{\infty} f(x) dx$.

  The answer I saw is to exchange the
  order of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and
  $\int_n^{\infty}$ as follows: $$
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_n^{\infty}
     f(x) dx
     = \int_1^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}  f(n) dx \leq
     \int_1^{\infty} \lfloor x \rfloor 
     f(x) dx $$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$
  is the greatest integer less than
  $x$. In this way, the answer proves the series converges. I was wondering why the two steps are valid? Is there some special meaning of the first equality? Because it looks similar to the tail sum formula for expectation of a random variable $X$ with possible values $\{ 0,1,2,...,n\}$: $$\sum_{i=0}^n i P(X=i) = \sum_{i=0}^n P(X\geq i).$$ The formula is from [Page 171 of Probability by Jim Pitman, 1993](http://books.google.com/books?id=L6IWgaCuilwC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=expectation++sum+of+%22tail+probabilities%22&source=bl&ots=yzHtpkh5PF&sig=OWGy7xmkkI0czpZgE7NDGwXVztw&hl=en&ei=HyA2TdvPCYGC8gbv4aCiCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAQ). Are they really related?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks, Greg O.! Could you please post again the equations you wrote before?

Comment: The exchange of the sum and integral in your second question is justified by Fubini's theorem, which typically is used to exchange the order of integration in iterated Lebesgue integrals, but more generally holds for iterated integrals in any (reasonable) measure space.  

In this case, if we set $g(x,n) = \chi_{[n,\infty)}(x)f(x)$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^\infty f(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{N}\int_1^\infty g\ dx \times d\mu$$ where $dx$ is Lebesgue measure on $[1,\infty)$ and $d\mu$ is counting measure on the natural numbers.  Now Fubini allows you to exchange the integrals as desired.

Comment: Possible repeat of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple example of a doubly indexed sequence $a_{m,n}$ for which you cannot exchange limits is given in Rudin's "Principles..." Example 7.2 pg. 144:

Let $a_{m,n} = \frac{m}{m+n}$, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{m,n} = 1,$$ but $$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{m,n} = 0.$$

Here is a previous post on this question which seems to thoroughly answer your other questions: [When can you switch the order of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits)

Answer (score 12):

A simpler example where one cannot switch the limits:
$$a_{m,n}=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }m\le n\\1&\text{if }m>n\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x+y}.$

You can also check the limit at the point $(0,0)$. Typical example of calculus.