# Exchange of two limits of a function

Tags: real-analysis

The question is simply given a function $f(x,y)$, when does $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to 0} f(x,y) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to 0} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f(x,y)$ hold?

I know that if the mixed limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0,y \to 0} f(x,y)$ exists, then above exchange is valid, but I think there should be more general conditions. Thanks!

Related post about limit of sequence: [When can we exchange order of two limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18041/when-can-we-exchange-order-of-two-limits).

Comment: A _sufficient_ condition is that $f$ be separately continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Moore-Osgood Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition) states that if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x,y)$ converges uniformly for $y\ne y_0$ and if $\lim_{y\to y_0}f(x,y)$ converges pointwise for $x\ne x_0$, then the iterated limits are equal with

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\lim_{y\to y_0}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to y_0}\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x,y)$$

Comment: Do you know where I can find the proof?

Comment: @MatheusManzatto I don't have a reference.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3ed, ch. 7.

Comment: Does not it matter which one converges uniformly and which one pointwise?

Comment: @VIVID It doesn't matter.  Just interchange $x$  and $y$.

Comment: @MarkViola Ok, thank you

Comment: @VIVID You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Is the formula still valid when $\lim_{y \to y_0} \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x, y) = \infty$?

Comment: @ColinTan If the conditions for the theorem to hold, then the double limit exists and equal to both iterated limits.