# In which conditions the limit of an infinite sum is equal to the infinite sum of the limits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X \neq \varnothing$ be a set, $\{x_k\}_{k\in \Bbb{N}} \subset X$ and $\{f_n : X \hookrightarrow[0,\infty]\}_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} \, \forall x \in X : f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$.

I want to know in which conditions
$$\sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} f_m(x_k) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} f_m(x_k)$$

My attempt guides me to the following by knowing that the limit of a increasing sequence is greater than all the elements of the sequence:
$$\forall n \in \Bbb{N} \, \forall x \in X : f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x) \Rightarrow \forall n,k \in \Bbb{N} : f_n(x_k) \leq f_{n+1}(x_k) \Rightarrow \forall n,k \in \Bbb{N}:f_n(x_k) \leq \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} f_m(x_k) \Rightarrow \forall n \in \Bbb{N}:\sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} f_n(x_k) \leq \sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} f_m(x_k) \Rightarrow \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} f_m(x_k) \leq \sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} f_m(x_k) $$

I don't know if the other inequality is true, neither which conditions should make it true. Any possible answers would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183291/exchange-of-two-limits-of-a-function/2183554#2183554) is a related theorem ...

Comment: The conditions you stated are sufficient, this is the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_2). This holds since $a_{m,k}=f_m(x_k)$ is non-negative and non-decreasing in $m$. Just to be clear: it also holds for $a_{m,k}=\infty$ or if any of the limits is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for my previous mistakes. I'm also currently learning real analysis and my knowledge is quite fragmented.

For simplicity I will write $f_m(k)$ instead of $f_m(x_k)$.[Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) in my previous response does not make full use of the conditions of monotonicity and non-negativeness of $f_m(x)$. Instead, this is exactly the statement of [Monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem):

> If for all $m,k\in\mathbb N, f_m(k)\in[0,+\infty]$ and $f_m(k)\le f_{m+1}(k)$, then
> $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(k)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}f_m(k)$$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183291/exchange-of-two-limits-of-a-function/2183554#2183554) is a related theorem ... not as powerful as the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but provides sufficient conditions for interchanging limits

Comment: Ricky, in the case of non-negative functions and monotone convergence, the hypothesis $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}M_k<\infty$ is not necessary, so you can remove it. You could also remove the hypothesis $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}f_m(k)\leqslant M_k$. See [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/monotone-convergence-theorem).

Comment: Sorry for my previous mistakes...My knowledge of real analysis is quite fragmented and makes me ignorant of such famous theorems as MCT. I suppose I had better learn more before answering...