# Interchanging the order of limits of a particular double sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like to interchange the iterated limits of a particular double sequence $a_{n,m}$, that is I would like that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{n,m}$.
The sequence has the following properties.

Firstly, it is actually formed by a sum over one of the variables of a double sequence $b_{n,i}$, so that $a_{n,m}=\sum_{i=1}^mb_{n,i}$, where $0\leq b_{n,i}\leq 1$. Hence for each fixed $n$, $a_{n,m}$ is an increasing sequence in $m$.

For each fixed $n$ the limit $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{n,m}=l_n$ exists, i.e. the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_{n,i}$ converges.

The iterated limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{n,m}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_{n,i}$ exists.

For each fixed $m$ the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^m b_{n,i}=\sum_{i=0}^m\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n,i}=p_m$ exists.

I know that if it were the case that $a_{n,m}\to l_n$ uniformly in $n$ then the double limit $\lim_{n,m\to\infty}a_{n,m}=a$ exists, and then since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m}=p_m$ exists, the iterated limits would commute and equal $a$ (as in [When can you switch the order of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits)), but I don't have uniformity.

So are the above properties sufficient for the the iterated limits to commute, or do I need something more?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://math.la.asu.edu/~jss/courses/fall06/mat472/limit_interchange.pdf (It's not an answer to the question; I think John has already answered the question; but it's a nice general treatment of interchange of limits and uniform convergence.)

Comment: @joriki thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $a_{n,m}=(1-1/m)^n$?  This is increasing in $m$, with limit $l_n=1$, so the iterated limit exists and equals $1$.  However, as $n$ goes to infinity, $a_{n,m}$ goes to $p_m = 0$.

Comment: An even simpler counterexample would be $b_{n,i}=\delta_{n,i}$, so $a_{n,m}=1$ if $m\ge n$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @Florian - I think that's a great example.  It gets to the heart of the matter.

Comment: Thank you both, two nice counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is not sufficient. Take $b_{n,i} = \dfrac1{(1 + 1/n)^i}$ for example.

Comment: This example doesn't satisfy that the iterated limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{n,m}$ exists, since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_{n,i}=n$.