# Interchanging the order of limits

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, limits, convergence-divergence

Would you advise me on the references of Pringsheim Convergence about interchanging the order of limits? Where can I find the most general statement?

Comment: More context on what you already know about it might help.  Did you do a web search and check out some of the many sources that come up?

Comment: Yes I would like to know where I can find a formal reference for the argument in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to have a (textbook/paper) reference for the results from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/15257/) by Arturo Magidin. (And perhaps for some similar results.) The simplest thing would be to ask him in a comment to his answer. Since you do not have the reputation for asking comments, I'll do that for you.

Comment: What is the relation between this approach and Arzela-Ascoli?