# Taking limit inside integration

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

What the conditions, other than DCT and MCT, under which $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n(x) \ \mathsf dx = \int lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \ \mathsf dx\quad  $$

where the $f_n$ are measurable functions?

DCT- Dominated Convergence Theorem 
MCT- Monotone Convergence Theorem

Comment: Vitali convergence theorem, Scheffe's lemma,...

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20100817081111/http://math.la.asu.edu/~jss/courses/fall06/mat472/limit_interchange.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the integrals may be interpreted as *definite* integrals, then we have in fact *iterated limits*, because the integrals are limits themselves too. Therefore the following issues are relevant to the question:

- [Commutativity of iterated limits](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548355/commutativity-of-iterated-limits)
- [Iterated Limits Schizophrenia](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597355/iterated-limits-schizophrenia)