# Uniform Probability and Riemann Sum

Tags: probability-theory, riemann-sum

Quoted from the Wikipedia page about
**[Natural Density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density)**:
*We see that this notion can be understood as a kind of probability
of choosing a number*, which obviously is the reason why Natural Densities are
*studied in probabilistic number theory*.
Standard mathematics says that it is *impossible* to have a uniform
probability distribution on the naturals. Meaning that it is impossible to have 
a distribution giving equal probabilities to each of (all) the natural numbers.

Not a question, however, about the same for an initial segment of the naturals.
The probability for picking, say, the number $7$ out of the initial segment
$\{1,2,3,4,5,\dots,n\}$ is simply: $1/n$. The same holds for an arbitrary
number $k$ in that segment.
And the sum of all the probabilities is $1/n + 1/n
+ \dots + 1/n = n.1/n = 1$, as it should.
But something weird happens if we
take the limit for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then each of the probabilities for
picking one natural number becomes $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n = 0$$
while the sum of all probabilities is still $1$, according to
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 = 1$$
How can this happen? A bunch of zeroes that sums up to one? Oh well, it's not
*just* a sum of zeroes. It's an *infinite* sum of zeroes.
But nevertheless.
Let's take another example, that seems only remotely resemblant. The following
trivial integral is expressed as the limit of a Riemann sum:
$$
  \int_0^1 dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^n 1/n
              = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n.1/n
              = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 = 1
$$
Am I blind or what? The *only* difference with the above "probabilities" is the
geometrical interpretation. Here come the probabilities. It is a histogram with
height of the blocks $1/n$ and width of the blocks $1$ for $n$ blocks. So the
total area of the blocks is $(n.1.1/n) = 1$ : 

[image]
And here comes the Riemann sum of the trivial integral. The blocks are $1/n$
wide, $1$ high and there are $n$ of them. The total area is $(n.1/n.1) = 1$.

[image]
Obviously, $\,\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n.1/n\,$ is *exactly the same
algebraic expression* with the integral as with our probabilities. But, on the the contrary, it seems that common mathematics has developed quite different
ideas about probabilities. The following is a standard **Theorem.**
Let $X$ be a random variable which assumes values in a countable infinite set
$Q$. We can prove there is no uniform distribution on $Q$ . As follows.
Assume there exists such a uniform distribution, that is, there
exists $a \ge 0$ such that $P(X = q) = a$ for every $q \in Q$ .
Observe that, since $Q$ is countable, by countable additivity of $P$ :
$$
  1 = P(X \in Q)=\sum_{q \in Q} P(X = q) = \sum_{q \in Q}  a 
$$
Observe that if $a = 0$ , $\sum_{q \in Q} a = 0$ . Similarly, if $a > 0$ ,
$\sum_{q \in Q} a = \infty$ . Contradiction.
Let's analyze.
The second part of this reasoning is remotely resemblant to the following
**[iterated limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548355/commutativity-of-iterated-limits)**:
$$
  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \left[ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{m}
  \right] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\; 0 = 0
$$ First
define uniform probabilities. It's easy to see that these will become zero if
the initial segment becomes infinite. Then sum up. Evidently the sum *then*
must be zero as well.
Here the variable $m$ has been introduced in order to avoid confusion with the
variable $n$.
But maybe this is the cause of the problem. Shouldn't we rather
write:
$$
  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \left[ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}
  \right] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\; 1/n = 1 \qquad \mbox{?}
$$
It seems that all of these problems would be solved if it were only possible to
define *infinitesimal probabilities* .. What is right and what is wrong?