# Is my proof correct (limits)?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

What I'm trying to prove is probably simple, but I want to know if this method specifically is valid. the goal is to show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0 \ \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=0$$ Assuming f is differentiable. Now $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$ implies that for any real $h$ we have $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x+h)-f(x) =0$$ Now if we restrict $h$ to be non-zero, we get this by dividing both sides by $h$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=0$$ Now define $g(h)$ as the above then $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \ g(h)=0$$But $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \ g(h)=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$$ and therefore $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=0$$

Comment: You've switched the order of your limits, so you're saying $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{h\to0}=\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{x\to\infty}$.  I think you need to justify that step.  You can't always switch the order.

Comment: Is that not allowed in general?

Comment: If it was allowed in general it's certainly not obvious.  So it needs to be justified.  But actually it's not true in general.

Comment: Here's an example showing you cannot always switch orders: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits

Comment: In general it would be the problem of determining if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \ \lim_{y \rightarrow b} f(x,y)=\lim_{y \rightarrow b} \ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x,y)$

Comment: Yes, but that's not true in absolute generality.

Comment: Yeah I just now saw your previous comment.

Comment: Consider a function that goes to zero but is wiggly, so that the derivative itself doesn't actually converge anywhere.

Comment: I actually did consider that but I couldn't think of a function that satisfies that property. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider something like $f(x)=\min\{\sin x,1/x\}$ where $\sin x\geq0$ and $\max\{\sin x,-1/x\}$ where $\sin x<0$.  That function won't be differentiable everywhere, in particular it won't be differentiable where the two curves $\sin x$ and $1/x$ meet.  But you can imagine smoothing out those corners so that it is differentiable everywhere, since those are just a countable discrete set of points.  Let $g$ be $f$ smoothed at those points.

Then the function $g$ would have limit zero as $x\to\infty$, but the derivative would equal one at every multiple of $2\pi$ so the derivative will not converge to anywhere as $x\to\infty$.

The problem with your proof is that you reverse the order of the two limits, you cannot always do that.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer!

Comment: No problem.  It wasn't exactly right as I first posted it but I edited it I think it's right now.

Answer (score 0):

I liked The idea, but the derivate is when h goes to zero, not to infinity.

I'd try to proof through formal definition, as real analysis tells us to do. Your question is if what you did is right, so I won't proof to you right now, but if you prefer I proof, just tell me.

The way I'd take is:
Get the definition of the derivate and the limit of f(x) to 0. So manipulate expressions to rewrite the initial limit into the derivate. (Using epsilons and deltas...)

Comment: It turns out the result is not true, we found a counter-example (see the other answer I posted) and the mistake is when he switches the order of the two limits.

Comment: Oh, it's true. I didn't pay attention totally to your answer because I was at street. Sorry.