# Can we interchange limits for weak convergence of double sequences?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

Let $(X_{n,m})_{n\geq 1,m\geq1}$ be a double sequence of random variables such that $X_{n,m}\Rightarrow X_m$ (weak convergence) as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $X_{n,m}\rightarrow X_n$ (almost sure convergence) as $m\rightarrow\infty$, and $X_m\rightarrow X$ (almost sure convergence) as $m\rightarrow\infty$. I am trying to determine whether these conditions are sufficient to establish that $X_n \Rightarrow X$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, or if not, what additional assumptions would have to be made in order to ensure the result. This is what I have done so far. Let $f$ be continuous and bounded. Using continuity of $f$ and then its boundedness (to apply dominated convergence theorem) we have:
$$\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(f(X_m))=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(f(X_{n,m})).$$
If I could interchange the two above limits, I would be able to conclude, since:
$$\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(f(X_{n,m}))=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(f(X_{n})),$$
also by continuity of $f$ and dominated convergence. However, I am having difficulties proving that we can effectively interchange these two limits (to do so, one of the two limits needs to be uniform), and wondering if the assumptions I currently have are sufficient? Any comments or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

update: I think it's probably better to consider $f$ to be continuous with compact support instead, as we can therefore use the uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: This might be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits

Comment: @DimitriosNt thanks for the link. Yes the method I am trying to use is listed there (Moore-Osgood theorem), but I am having trouble establishing either weak convergence of $X_{n,m}$ to $X_n$ uniformly in $m$ or weak convergence of $X_{n,m}$ to $X_m$ uniformly in $n$..