# Exchange the order of limits

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of functions $g_n$ in $x$ that converges pointwise to some function.

Is $$\lim_{t \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int g_n(x-t) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{t \to 0}  \int g_n(x-t) dx$$?
Is this always the case? If not, what conditions are needed to be satisfied first before this is considered true?

EDIT: My original question was wrongly written. This is the question I want to ask instead.

Comment: When you say that the sequence $g_n$ converges, do you mean pointwise or uniformly?

Comment: Perhaps the [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) may be of value?

Comment: I think in this case, no. I am not trying to put the limit inside the integral.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15240/29024