# Limit of partial derivative

Tags: limits, partial-derivative

Let $S(x,y)$ be a postive real value function defined on $(0,\infty)\times(a,b)$ that has both partial derivatives and satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} S(x,y)=0$ for every given $y$ in $(a,b)$.

Prove or disprove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\partial S}{\partial y}=0$$ for every $y$ in $(a,b)$.

Comment: it is advisable to include our attempt when we post a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} = \lim_{\delta y\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{S(x, y+\delta y)-S(x,y)}{\delta y}\right)$$
Hence,
$$\begin {align} \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial y}\right) & = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\lim_{\delta y\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{S(x, y+\delta y)-S(x,y)}{\delta y}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{\delta y\rightarrow 0}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{S(x, y+\delta y)-S(x,y)}{\delta y}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{\delta y\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow0}}(S(x,y+\delta y))-\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow0}}(S(x, y))}{\delta y}\right)\\
&=\lim_{\delta y \rightarrow0}\left(\frac{0-0}{\delta y}\right)\\
&=0
\end{align}$$
Hence the proof is complete.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Since $x$ and $\delta y$ are independent of each other, this can be done.

Comment: I think my case satisfies [the conditions to swap limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits).

Comment: Usually, it requires at least one of the limit to be uniformly convergent to justify the eligibility of interchanging limits. Can you elaborate more on that?