# Computing: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{nk^2+k+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to find an equivalence at infinity  to the following sequence.
$$C_n= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{nk^2+k+1}$$
Here are the given questions

> 1-Find the $\lim_{n\to\infty}C_n$
>
> 2- If the limit blows up give an equivalence at infinity.

For the first question, I set $$C_n(k)=  \frac{n}{nk^2+k+1}$$

then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}C_n(k) =\frac{1}{k^2} $$ and I proved that the sequence $(C_n(k))_n$ is monotone
it therefore springs from monotone convergence
that,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}C_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{nk^2+k+1}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{nk^2+k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Is this reasoning  correct if yes then I am interested on knowing some more elegant way (if there is some) of solving this. if not give me answer. I am don't how to solve the question in the case the limit is infinity.

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ is wrong, but if you started all your sums at $k=1$, it would make sense. And it would be elegant enough without all those many typos.

Comment: @ProfessorVector you are right it is up to thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}\qquad\left(\scriptstyle{\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)}\right)$$
hence by factoring $k^2+\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n}$
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{n}{n k^2+k+1}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\zeta(3)+\zeta(4)}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$
Needless to say, the first terms of the asymptotic expansion can be found by creative telescoping™ too.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

The first term of the series is $n$.  For the remaining part, note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{k^2}-\frac{1}{k^2+\frac{k+1}{n}}\right)\right|&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k+1}{k^2\left(k^2+\frac{k+1}{n}\right)}\\\\&\le \frac2n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The OP starts all sums at $k=0$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yes, I know.  This is a "HINT" only.  Surely, the OP can remove the offending term, $n$.  I've edited to discuss the presence of the first term.

Comment: I've commented, there was no "cowardly". The ignored $k=0$ was only one reason, I politely didn't mention "rep wh...ing": the "quality" of the question was subterranean, and your answer didn't address that at that time.

Comment: In what way is the 'quality' of this question subterranean? The language is perhaps a little awkward but OP has asked a sensible question, given their own reasoning, and asked for it to be checked. I'm not going to disagree that we should have solid standards for questions but this one shows more effort than _many_ of the questions around here.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Those sums starting at $k=0$ are *not* sensible, and the OP didn't correct that even after being told. Yes, there is own effort, that's why I didn't downvote the question, but somebody who answers should know better, and address the mistakes.

Comment: @ProfessorVector if I change to $k=1$ then jack have to update hi result. which is correct

Comment: @ProfessorVector I changed now I think is result perfecly feet now

Answer (score 0):

From integration point of view, $C_n=\int_{\Bbb N} f(n,k) d m(k)$ with $f(n,k)= \frac{n}{nk^2+k+1}$ where $dm$ is counting measure: m(A)=# A= card (A). We clearly have that
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} f(n,k)= g(k)=\frac{1}{k^2}\quad \text{and}\quad f(n,k)\leq g(k)=\frac{1}{k^2}\in L^1(\Bbb N, dm)$$
since
$$\int_{\Bbb N} g(k) d m(k)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

By convergence dominated theorem we have
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} C_n= \int_{\Bbb N} \lim_{n\to \infty} f(n,k) d m(k)=\int_{\Bbb N}g(k)d m(k)=\sum_{k\in \Bbb N} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$