# If $f_n$ converges uniformly and that exists a sequence $\{t_n\}$ such that $f_n(t_n)\to x$, does this imply that $t_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a problem that essentially boils down to the above question. Another important fact is that $f$ is continuous. My approach has basically been a proof by contradiction. We assume that the sequence doesn't converge. However, we also know, by assumption, that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(t_n) = x.
\end{equation}
Now, since $f$ is continuous, we can take the limit inside and get
\begin{equation}
f\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n\right) = x
\end{equation}
which would contradict the fact that $t_n$ doesn't converge.

I sort of feel uneasy about this approach. Is it correct, and if not, how can I improve it?

Comment: "Now, since $f$ is continuous". There is no $f$ in that limit: there are a bunch of $f_n$; and while $f_n$ are continuous, they also depend on $n$ and so cannot be taken out of the limit. You are not calculating $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_n(t_k)$ (which *would* be equivalent to $f_n(\lim_{k\to\infty} t_k)$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What other restrictions do I have to impose on $f$ to get the limit inside the function?

Comment: The point is that there is no $f$ in the limit. You never even said what $f$ was, but I assume it is supposed to be the limit of the $f_n$.

Comment: part1. i think the fallacy here is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(t_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n)$$ @ArturoMagidin ? it seems like OP knows something's wrong but is unable to articulate precisely what is wrong. so yeah. it sounds a little like [Freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)...

Comment: part2. i'm thinking it's like $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n b_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n)$$ for sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, although in this case i believe this is right assuming the limits exist (and are finite). as for the case of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(t_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n)$$ assuming the limits exist...i forgot the rules. probably some uniformity thing, but i have a feeling that the limits exist isn't enough

Comment: @BCLC: Well, yes, that first display makes no sense. As to your second one, it is an instance of problems with double-indexed families, which are *very* tricky. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits/15257#15257). Here it is worse, because you are only "going down the diagonal", so a *lot* of information gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose that each $f_n$ is the null function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ and that $t_n=(-1)^n$. Then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t_n)=0$, but $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges.

Comment: Didn't think of that. However, if I also know that $|f[\mathbb{R}]|>1$ how would this change the outcome?

Comment: Do you mean that each $f_n$ is non-constant? Not really. Just take $f_n(x)=x^2$ and the same sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. One final question. Is it always the case that we have to know an explicit formula for each of the $f_n$s and $t_n$s to be able to say something about the limit in question?

Comment: Since the statement is false, the natural way of doing things is to provide a counter example. However, in this case, if, for some $c\in\Bbb R$, $f_n(x)=c$, then *any* divergent $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ would have worked.