# Limit evaluation for a infinite series

Tags: limits

Show that:-
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }    \frac{1}{6x^2} - \frac{1}{120x^4} +.... ({-1})^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!x^{2n}}$$ for $n\geq1$ where n $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^+}$ is equal to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

> My method was as the form of the limit is $\infty - \infty$ , so i tried first assuming limit exists and taking common denominator for a finite n and tried with lhopital if the limit exists but it was not working , may anyone tell ?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you trying to compute the following: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{(2i+1)x^{2i}}$$ If this is what you are trying to solve then use Stolz-Cesaro (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Comment: Yeah right @Marcos okay will see it

Comment: If you want to interchange limits, then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits

Comment: Nice thanks @Marcos

Comment: **Hint** Divide by $x$ and make $x=\frac 1y$ and you are very close to a well know series

Comment: Thanks pretty nice @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}({-1})^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!x^{2n}}$$

---

$$\frac{e^{x}-1-x}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!} $$

$$\frac{e^{1/x}-1-\frac1x}{\frac1x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!x^{n}}$$

$$\frac{e^{1/x}-1-\frac1x}{\frac1{x}}+\frac{e^{1/-x}-1+\frac1x}{\frac1{-x}}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!x^{2n}}$$

$$x({e^{1/x}}-{e^{1/-x}}-\frac2x)=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!x^{2n}}$$

Substituting $ x \to ix$

$$ix({e^{1/ix}}-{e^{1/-ix}}-\frac{2}{ix})=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{({-1})^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!x^{2n}}$$

$$S=-\frac{ix}2(e^{-i/x}-e^{i/x}+\frac{2i}x)$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}S=1$$

Comment: Where do you justify interchanging the limits? The question wants $x\to0$ first, and *then* $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Lorago my knowledge in mathematics is way too little to comprehend the complexities of the monotone convergence theorem. In case the interchange is valid, I'll leave this as a reference to future readers, despite the downvotes.

Comment: Added the substitution text. I guess one issue is that when you substitued $ x \to ix$ , the amount of mathematical theory to describe what you've done formally increased quite a bit because you're then dealing with a complex limit. In the complex plane, you're essentially approaching the origin along the line $y=0$ (see how the ix expression varies).

Comment: This a quite a bit complex method, i didnt understood clearly but i am fine with dealing with this later so as to get what it fully means

Comment: @Aplateofmomos I simply tried to manipulate the taylor expansion to the desired form and I'm surprised to see that there are so many nuances to it(multivariable limit, limit interchange, etc.). Please forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: I understand, don't worry :) @DatBoi