# When can the order of limits of a multivariable function be exchanged?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

There are many posts on this site discussing exchanging the order of a limits of a single variable function.  I would like to confirm my application of it to a multivariable function:

If *(but not only if)* $\lim_{x \to a}f(x,y)$ is defined and continuous for all $y$ in an open interval around $b$ (except possibly at $b$ itself) AND $\lim_{y \to b}f(x,y)$ is defined and continuous for all $x$ in an open interval around $a$ (except possibly at $a$ itself), then $$\lim_{x \to a}[\lim_{y \to b}f(x,y)] = \lim_{y \to b}[\lim_{x \to a}f(x,y)].$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Try $a=b=0$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: You'll be wanting the [Moore-Osgood theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Moore-Osgood_theorem_for_interchanging_limits) The counterexample proposed in the first comment due to the stronger condition of uniform convergence rather than pointwise convergence.

Comment: [Related, for sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15240/742).